# Can I lose content from gamesharing if I deactivate the other person's account?

Tags: ps3

If my friend [gameshared](http://www.ps3blog.co.za/guides/playstation-3-game-sharing/) something with me and I deactivate his account from my PS3, do I lose what he gameshared me? For instance, DLC for Black ops?

Answer (score 7):

**Deactivating the second account from your PS3 will make all of the content from that account inaccessible.** However, if you reactivate the account, the content will be accessible again.

---

Answer from [this](http://www.neogaf.com/forum/showpost.php?p=6320813&postcount=1) source:

> When a PS3 is activated under a given PSN account, it can run the software downloaded (purchased) from the PlayStation store under that
>   PSN account. The activation is automatic the first time you log in
>   with a given PSN account, meaning whatever you download from then on
>   will work fine.
>
> **Deactivating a PS3 (or a PSP) basically makes content downloaded under a given PSN account unreadable on that system. You can safely
>   try this yourself. Deactivate your system - try launching any already
>   downloaded game (wont work) - re-activate your system  - content will
>   now work fine as before.**
>
> This is mostly useful when you want to share stuff you downloaded (purchased) with other people. To do so you have to let them log in as
>   you from their PS3s. So you basically have to give them your log in
>   data (email + password). Once they log in as you, their PS3s are
>   automatically activated (hence, by accessing the "Download List"
>   section on the PS store, they can re-download for free and run on
>   their systems all the stuff you purchased). When a grand total of 5
>   PS3s are activated under the same PSN account (this includes your own
>   system), no more PS3s can be activated, therefore you cannot share
>   your PSN account with more that 4 other people at a time.
>
> If, say, you want to share your PSN account with a new friend but have all those extra 4 activations already in place on other PS3s, you
>   have to de-activate one of these so that your new friend can activate
>   his system under your PSN account.
>
> Also note that deleting a profile via the XMB from a PS3 doesn't automatically deactivate it under the PSN account associated to that
>   profile. It has to be "manually" deactivated from the account
>   management page in order to free one of those 5 activations. So if a
>   friend of yours is using your PSN account and decides to dispose of
>   his PS3 system, tell him to do the deactivation thing (log in as you >
>   Account Management > Activate System > PlayStation 3 (this system) >
>   Deactivate system), otherwise you'll lose one of your possible
>   activations. Simply deleting the profile associated with your PSN
>   account or formatting the HDD is not enough.

This seems to be a generally accepted answer across multiple forums. This has been quoted several times with positive responses.

Comment: Does that mean you can add an account, activate it, delete it and the content bought with it will still be accessible as long as it remains on the HDD?